# Cypress - Stubing/Mocking redux hooks in mountHook in cypress-react-unit-test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, cypress

I am trying to unit test a custom hook which also uses redux hook, like `useSelector` & `useDispatch` but I am getting an error that the hook is not wrapped in `Provider`. I am using `cypress-react-unit-test` to mount the hook but am not sure how to get around the provider issue. Any help is appreciated.

Internally they call the hook inside a component, so I was wondering if there is a way we can change that.

```
  it('Check Groups keys for String', () => {
    mountHook(() => useGroups())
      .then(uesGroupsResults => {
        // assert here...
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The mountHook function accepts a second options argument. One of the options is `wrapper`. This can be set to a React component, e.g. a provider.

An example (from the recently updated `cypress-react-unit-test` documentation) is:

```
import { mountHook } from 'cypress-react-unit-test'
const wrapper = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
mountHook(() => useCustomHook(), { wrapper })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you reference the now archived `cypress-react-unit-test`. Then, I cannot find any `mountHook()` options and thus wrapper support in the latest stable release of @cypress/react at 4.16.4.